# What type of relation it is?

Tags: database, relationship

I have table Customer, CreditCard, TypeOfCreditCard. CreditCard belongs to customer (every customer coul'd have one or more credit cards, so relation is one-to-many). Then table CreditCard (IdCustomer, IdCard(PK), NumberCard, IdTypeOfCard). Then TypeOfCard table have (IdType(PK), Name). CreditCard and TypeOfCreditCard have relation, i decide. that if type can change name, it what be bad to change db, so added new table Type... But what relation is between this 2 tables? I think taht is one-to-one, is that right?

Comment: This just doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like every credit card can only have one type, but every type can have multiple credit cards, *if* I'm reading your question correctly. So that would be one to many.

Comment: maybe, I didn't know 100% what I want, see types could be: international, country, etc... every card have one type, but do you think every type could have some more cards?

Comment: Again, this is totally my perspective of the question without detailed knowledge of what you're trying to accomplish. If your types were "international" and "country", and your cards were "Discovery" and "MasterCard", it would make sense to me that while each card could only have one type (it's either an international card or a national) each type could have more than one card (both Discovery and MasterCard could be international).

Comment: So is this question answered now, or are you still having issues with it?

Comment: i have yet now time, wait a week pls